# Finding the Wronskian of the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation that i need to find the Wronskians of.

$$y''-2\tan(t)y'+(1+2\tan^2(t))y=0$$

on the interval $-\pi/2<x<\pi/2$

Assume that $y_1,y_2$ are any two solutions of this equation. How to find the Wronskian?

I tried to turn the equation to a characteristic equation but it leads to nowhere. How do I go about this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the wronskian $w$ of $$y'' + by' + cy = 0 $$ satisfies the differential equation 
$$w' = -bw = 2\frac{\sin t}{\cos t } w \to \frac{dw}{w} = \frac{2 \sin t \, dt}{\cos t} = -\frac{d\, \cos t}{\cos t}   $$ solution is $$w = \frac{C}{\cos^2t} $$ we can integrate $$\ln w = \int \frac{dw}{w} = -2 \int \frac{d \, \cos t}{\cos t} = - 2 \ln (\cos t) + \ln C = \ln \left(\frac{C}{\cos^2 t}\right)  $$  exponentiating the last result gives the result claimed before.

---

$\bf edit:$ let $y_1, y_2$ satisfy $$y_1'' + by_1' + cy_1 = 0, y_2''+by_2' + cy_2 = 0$$ multiply the first one by $y_2$,  the second one by $y_1$ and subtract. you get 
$$y_1''y_2 - y_2''y_1 + b(y_1'y_2 - y_2'y_1) = 0 \to (y_1'y_2 - y_1y_2')' + b(y_1'y_2-y_1y_2')= 0$$ that is $$w' = -bw \text{ where } w =  y_1'y_2-y_1y_2'. $$

Comment: Answered by none other than Abel himself!

Comment: @abel How did you get this $\frac{dw}{w} = \frac{2 \sin t \, dt}{\cos t}$

Comment: So this is a formula that you use, right? @abel?

Comment: @MarionCrane, i will edit my answer.

Comment: @abel Thanks for your answer. I still have questions tho. $\frac{dw}{w} = \frac{2 \sin t \, dt}{\cos t}$ How did you get this?

Comment: @MarionCrane, for your differential equation $b = - 2 \tan t = - 2 \frac{\sin t}{\cos t}$. am i missing something?

Comment: @abel No, I get that, but when you differentiate that, i am not sure about the way you have written it. I do not get how you differentiated it